# firefox and chrome keep crashing on lubuntu 19.04 and ubuntu 18.04 ff ver 68.0.2

Tags: browser

firefox and chrome keep crashing on lubuntu 19.04 and ubuntu 18.04 ff ver 68.0.2
this is on a 4000 series ?? i7 with 8 gig ram 120 ssd, no video card 
i have another pc hooked on network that has had no issues in the last 6 days with chrome and ff
i`ve changed Ethernet ports on router and back of i7 pc
i`ve changed Ethernet cables that are 2 ft long
i`ve disable hardware acceleration on both browsers
i wasn`t having an issue until about 3 weeks ago 
im fixing to try puppy linux on my usb drive for a couple of days

Comment: I don't understand your issue, you've clouded it with two releases (Ubuntu & Lubuntu), then mentioned trying an off-topic distro as if more up-to-date.  We don't support Puppy so that's off-topic and we cannot help there.  Your post is most unclear & possibly off-topic

Comment: @guiverc OP hasn't actually tried Puppy Linux yet, only Lubuntu 19.04 and Ubuntu 18.04, so this question can't be construed as off topic. Maybe it's too broad because of both Lubuntu and Ubuntu, but I personally would let that go because solving it for one OS probably also solves it for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry people i went into my bios and reset it to factory defaults 
please don`t try this at home :) its only for the fool hardy!!
The aforementioned browsers are now both working without a hiccup 
Solved ?????? who know`s with technology today